# Query about pandas copy() method

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa','bbb','ccc'], 'B':[1,2,3]})
df2=df1.copy()
df1.loc[0,'A']='111' #modifying the 1st element of column A
print df1
print df2
```

When modifying `df1` the object `sf2` is not modified. I expected it because I used `copy()`

```
s1=pd.Series([[1,2],[3,4]])
s2=s1.copy()
s1[0][0]=0 #modifying the 1st element of list [1,2]
print s1
print s2
```

But why did `s2` changed as well in this case? I expected no change of `s2` because I used `copy()` to create it, but for my surprise, when modifying `s1` the object `s2` is also modified. I don't get why.

Answer (score 5):

This is occurring because your `pd.Series` is of dtype=object, so it essentially copied a bunch of references to python objects. Observe:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s1=pd.Series([[1,2],[3,4]])
   ...:

In [3]: s1
Out[3]:
0    [1, 2]
1    [3, 4]
dtype: object

In [4]: s1.dtype
Out[4]: dtype('O')
```

Since `list` objects are mutable, then the operation:

```
s1[0][0]=0
```

Modifies the list *in-place*.

This behavior is a "shallow copy", which *normally* isn't an issue with `pandas` data structures, because normally you would be using a numeric data type in which case shallow copies don't apply, or if you do use the object dtype you would be using python string objects, which are immutable.

Note, `pandas` containers have a different notion of a deep-copy. Notice the `.copy` method has a default `deep=True`, but from the documentation:

> When `deep=True` (default), a new object will be created with a copy
>   of the calling object's data and indices. Modifications to the data or
>   indices of the copy will not be reflected in the original object (see
>   notes below).
>
> When `deep=False`, a new object will be created without copying the
>   calling object's data or index (only references to the data and index
>   are copied). Any changes to the data of the original will be reflected
>   in the shallow copy (and vice versa). ... When `deep=True`, data is
>   copied but actual Python objects will not be copied recursively, only
>   the reference to the object. This is in contrast to `copy.deepcopy` in
>   the Standard Library, which recursively copies object data (see
>   examples below).

Again, this is because `pandas` is designed for using numeric dtypes, with some built-in support for `str` objects. A `pd.Series` of `list` objects is very strange indeed, and really not a good use-case for a `pd.Series`.

Answer (score 2):

When you copied the `s1` object, it actually created a new, separate Series object and referenced it to `s2` - just as you expected. However, the two list *within* the `s1` Series object were not duplicated with the Series. It simply copied their references.

See [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-in-a/0596001886/ch04s03.html) for a good starting point towards understanding the difference between a Python `reference` and an `object`.

Simply put, a Python `variable` is not the same thing as the actual  Python object. Variables (like `s1` and `s2`) are simply references that point to the memory location where the actual object lives.

Because the original Series object `s1` contained two list references, versus two list objects, only the `references` for the internal list objects were copied (not the list objects themselves).

```
import pandas as pd

s1=pd.Series([[1,2],[3,4]])
# The oject referenced by variable "s1" has a memory address
print ("s1:", hex(id(s1)))
s2=s1.copy()
# The oject referenced by variable "s2" has a different memory address
print ("s2:", hex(id(s2)))
# However when you copied "s1", the 
# list items within only had their references copied
# So "s1[0]" and "s2[0]" are simply references to the same object
print ("s1[0]:", hex(id(s1[0])))
print ("s2[0]:", hex(id(s2[0])))
```

OUTPUT:

```
s1: 0x7fcdf5678898 # A different address form s2
s2: 0x7fcddee25240 # A different address form s1
s1[0]: 0x7fcdddf9f6c8 # The same address for the first list
s2[0]: 0x7fcdddf9f6c8 # The same address for the first list
```

`@juanpa.arrivillaga` is correct in her answer that you need to use a [deep copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)